# Share and save a contact with click on link in browser

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, django, qr-code, vcf-vcard

**I have a query?**
I want to save contact. when i click on the link which is mention in website.
how to do?

## Its work on mobile application( QR. Code Scanner).

When i scan a Qr code of contact.after that the scanner open a contact app and ask to save a contact. it work both android and IOS(Apple device).

The same process,i want to without scan a code. when i click a link in browser contact app open and ask me to save a contact in mobile device.

I am doing this functionality in Python with Django Framework.
what is do to do that?

## How Work on mobile device.

Step 1. First a QR code of contact with this website.  [Qr code generator](https://qr-code-generator.com/)
Step 2. then i select a VCARD , fill the form and submitted.
Step 3. after that it will generate a QR image code.
Step 4. then i open a mobile scanner app to scan this code.
Step 5. it will redirect and open a contact app to save this contact.

I am doing this functionality in Python with Django Framework.
what is do to do that?

#django #python #QRcode #VCARD #Conact #Javascipt #Share